# HttpClient : hostname didn't match - accessible from browser but not from code

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am trying to access a website from my code using HttpClient :

```
CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();

HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("https://www.datamed.org/search.php?query=gene&searchtype=data");

ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
String responseBody = httpclient.execute(httpget, responseHandler);
```

This is the error i am getting :

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLException: hostname in certificate didn't match: <www.datamed.org> != <ucrexdc.ucsd.edu> OR <ucrexdc.ucsd.edu>
```

I checked the certificate from browser, it seems correct, with correct names.
Not sure from where it is picking up `ucrexdc.ucsd.edu` .

The code does work if I use a proxy.
Gone through a lot of similar issues on StackOverflow, but in most cases the server was under user's control. In my case, this is an already existing website. and i have this problem only for this website.

Can it be a problem with my environment?

UPDATE:

I found out that both the websites (`datamed.org` and `ucrexdc.ucsd.edu`) have the same IP , `169.228.51.21` . Can it be a problem, why doesn't the browser have issues with this?

UPDATE 2:

I was using apache `http-client 4.3.1`,
When i updated to `4.4.1`, it was resolved. the issue was most possibly related to SNI.

Comment: this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642777/trusting-all-certificates-using-httpclient-over-https

Comment: have seen, it suggests a workaround, which shouldn't be used in prod code. moreover i also want to know what is causing this to happen

Comment: @ScaryWombat new to this, did not see any Keystore code in the examples. I am able to connect to google.com without any keystore thoguh. also, datamed.org is not on my server.

Comment: The browser works because it supports SNI (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication). Which version of Java are you using?

Comment: @msbit i am using Java 1.8

Comment: Hmm, well SNI has been supported since Java 1.7, so it's likely something else.

Comment: @msbit ohk, any ideas why it works with a proxy?

Comment: Not sure, could be related in as much as the proxy only hosts the one site via SSL, so something like SNI isn't required for contacting it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130073/discussion-between-msbit-and-gaurav5430).

Answer (score 0):

HttpClient provides two implementations for Hostname verification.

1. DefaultHostnameVerifier
2. NoopHostnameVerifier

by default HttpClient uses **DefaultHostnameVerifier**  implementation. You can try the different hostname verifier implementation.

```
SSLContext sslContext = SSLContexts.createSystemDefault();
SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslsf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext,  NoopHostnameVerifier.INSTANCE);
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().setSSLSocketFactory(sslsf).build();
```

Comment: DO NOT ever do this in production code. I have encountered too many situations where something like this has been left in. This is BEGGING for a hijack or attack. Learn how TLS works and how certificates are involved DO NOT DO THIS.

Comment: @DaveG Thanks for information Dave. Do you know good documentation for TLS.

Comment: This is probably a good starting point https://www.sans.org/reading-room/whitepapers/protocols/ssl-tls-beginners-guide-1029. There are a significant number of resources available to you on this subject. I would pose a stackoverflow question. You may be prompted with other similar or exact questions.